# Android Studio Error: Unable to create project

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded and installed `Android Studio 2.3.1` but I am unable to create Project.
I get a plugin exception.

> com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: com/android/tools/idea/project/messages/AbstractSyncMessages [Plugin: com.android.tools.apk]

[image: Error image]

Please find a solution to this problem.

Comment: You installed Android Studio version  `2.3.1` shouldn't it be `3.1.4`

Comment: your issue was solved as per below answer?

Comment: Can I not use the version 2.3.1? Is the solution only to update it?

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio 2.3.1 is outdated... Please use the latest Android Studio 3.1.4 and check if the problem persists

[Download Android Studio Latest](https://developer.android.com/studio/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your Android Studio to the latest version (3.1.4).

1. On the top menu, select Help -> Check for Update...
2. Upon the updates dialog below, select Updates link to configure your IDE settings.

[image]

3. Then press **Update and Restart**.

After updating Android Studio then create project again. It will be solved your problem.

Or

You can download the latest version of Android studio from the [developer portal](https://developer.android.com/studio/).

Comment: Is it just because of version?

Comment: Maybe. Your Studio version is so downgraded version. If you have the same problem after updating the Android Studio then we try to provide the possible solution for this.